# VB Registry Call in Debug and Release Configurations on 64-Bit Windows 7 Machine

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, registry

I am using Visual Studio 2010 on a 64-bit Win7 machine at home and a 32-bit Win7 machine at work.  On the 32-bit machine, in the IDE, this call works in both debug and release configurations:

openVPNExePath = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OpenVPN", "exe_path", "")

But, on the 64-bit machine the call returns a valid value in the debug configuration, but  sets openVPNExePath to Nothing in the release configuration.

I have the target CPU set to x86, because the app references a 32-bit dll.

This may have nothing to do with 32 vs 64-bit.  Is there a security setting somewhere that I should know about?  Can someone put me on the right track?

Comment: If you run as administrator in release do you get the correct value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target CPU is a per-configuration setting.  So it is very easy to set it correctly for the Debug configuration.  But forget to do it again for the Release configuration.

Do be aware that you will actually read HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\OpenVPN since you forced 32-bit mode.  So double-check with Regedit.exe if that is correct.  If it is not then you will have to use [RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to force the 64-bit view.

Comment: Both excellent points!  I now realize I had the target CPU set in only the release configuration.  That's why my call worked in the debug config but not the release.  Good information!